# add label to node using embedded API

Tags: java, neo4j

Using Neo4j 2.0 milestone 3

Currently have this code (working code)

```
String DB_PATH = "/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/community-1.8.1-unix/libexec/data/graph.db";
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
try {
   Node myNode = graphDb.createNode();

tx.success();
}
finally {
   tx.finish();
}
```

This is the embedded API.  How can I add a label to my node?  Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to create a label first by creating an Enum that `implements Label`, or use `DynamicLabel` to create one on the fly.

Once you have created, you will have to add it to the `Node`.

The below shows you how to do it with `DynamicLabel`:

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.DynamicLabel;

Label myLabel = DynamicLabel.label("Label_Name");
myNode.addLabel(myLabel);
```

You also have to do this within a Transaction.