# How to change label of a node in neo4j?

Tags: java, neo4j

I read the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111944/add-label-to-node-using-embedded-api) to create the label of node through embedded Java Api. But in my problem the label is dynamic because of correction. So, is there a way to change the label?

Without this facility the alternate solution I have thought is to create nodes of 'labels' and  create edge from entity node to that 'label' node. But this may lead to some disadvantages as not able to make use of index over the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove labels from nodes using:

```
node.removeLabel(DynamicLabel.label("MyLabel"));
```

And you can find all the nodes with the incorrect label using the global operations:

```
GlobalGraphOperations.at(graphDB).getAllNodesWithLabel( DynamicLabel.label("MyLabel") );
```

Comment: Hey, can you provide some reference for all the java embedded apis?